# Managing a mailing list

Tags: mailman

Using mailman version 2.1.4 trying to set the reply to only the mailing list administrator how do l go about this 
I have tried defining an explicit address and also setting the number of addresses to reply yo still no luck

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the `Reply-To:` header to be the list admin's address?

Answer (score 1):

The variables you want are called **reply_goes_to_list** and **reply_to_address**; they are set in the *General Options* page of the web interface, in the section *Reply-To: header munging*.

The first should be toggled to *Explicit address* and the second set to the address of the list admin.